# Can I use such as with proper names?

Tags: word-usage

Is it proper grammar to use "such as" with proper names? For example:

"Studio musicians, such as Jimmy Page ..."

"Like" wouldn't work since it is ambiguous, yet "such as" just doesn't seem correct to me. That is, can a person be a "such?"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Like* and *such as* are perfectly fine here, and a simple web search should confirm a plethora of contemporary examples of both *such as Jimmy page* (e.g. [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0b0g902)), and *like Jimmy Page* (e.g. *[Rolling Stone](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/features/greta-van-fleet-black-smoke-rising-album-tour-w518444)*). Is there a particular rule or guideline you were taught that *such* is only used with the inanimate? I'm afraid I'm quite unclear on your question.

Comment: Actually, *studio musicians, like Jimmy Page,  . . .* is fine.  Most people would not interpret it ambiguously. (And if you remove the commas—to say that studio musicians have good feelings towards him—that meaning isn't ambiguous either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to use "such as" in this context. Especially when you are naming or listing people as examples of a particular characteristic (studio musicians, in this case). And avoids the potential ambiguity.

This page has more on [Difference Between Such As and Like](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-such-as-and-like/)